# How to add clicked button position to session

Tags: java, android, session, button

I have implemented a small shopping cart project, there is a list of products with a button. When i click a "ADD" button it will change the button name "ADD" to "REMOVE" and color also changing Green to Red. Here my problem is if i revisit the products form clicked button should be "REMOVE" and red color. So how to add clicked button position to session.

My code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            final ViewHolderGrid holderForGrid;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.consumer_catalog_list_item, null);
                holderForGrid = new ViewHolderGrid(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holderForGrid);

            } else {
                holderForGrid = (ViewHolderGrid) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final BusinessCatalogVariables Catalog = catalogList.get(position);




            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setClickable(false);
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setTag(position);

            if (catalogList.get(position).isAdded()) {
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Remove");
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnred);
            } else {
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to Cart");
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsignup);
            }

            if (Pref_Storage.checkDetail(context, Items)) {
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Remove");
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnred);
                Toast.makeText(context, Items, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to Cart");
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsignup);
            }

            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                    Log.d("ADD BUTTON POSITION:", "position=" + position);

                    if (holderForGrid.AddtoCart.getText().equals("Add to Cart")) {

                        catalogList.get(position).setAdded(true);
                        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Remove");
                        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnred);


                        Items = String.valueOf(Position);
                        Pref_Storage.setDetail(context, Items, "added");

//                      

                    } else if (holderForGrid.AddtoCart.getText().equals("Remove")) {

                        catalogList.get(position).setAdded(false);
                        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsignup);
                        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to Cart");


                        Items = String.valueOf(Position);
                        Pref_Storage.deleteKey(context,Items);


                    }


                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Try to maintain the state of the product using model class (POJO), i.e instead of using holderForGrid.AddtoCart.getText().equals("Add to Cart") change the code to check the product status based on the model class, something like product.isAdded()(Product is model/pojo class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use setTag(),getTag() method,

Class Pref_Storage.java [For storing products id]

```
public class Pref_Storage {
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    public static void openPref(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void deleteKey(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        if (b) {
            Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.remove(key);

            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
            prefsPrivateEditor = null;
            Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
        }
    }

    public static void setDetail(Context context, String key, String value) {
        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        Editor prefsPrivateEditor = Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsPrivateEditor.putString(key, value);

        prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
        prefsPrivateEditor = null;
        Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences = null;
    }

    public static Boolean checkDetail(Context context, String key) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Pref_Storage.openPref(context);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : Pref_Storage.sharedPreferences.getAll()
                .entrySet()) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        boolean b = result.containsKey(key);
        return b;
    }
}
```

And in Adapter Class you have to check:

```
    if(Pref_Storage.checkDetail(context, pid)){
        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Remove");
    }
    else{
        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to Cart");
    }

    holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setTag(position);
    holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
            Button btn=(Button)v;

            if (btn.getText().equals("Add to Cart")) {
                catalogList.get(position).setAdded(true);
                btn.setText("Remove");
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnred);
                Pref_Storage.setDetail(context, pid, "added");
            } else if (btn.getText().equals("Remove")) {

                catalogList.get(position).setAdded(false);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsignup);
                btn.setText("Add to Cart");
                Pref_Storage.deleteKey(context,pid);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if i click a button and if i revisit the form it should be in clicked state

Comment: You are storing data in Local DB or SharedPreferences?

Comment: No i am not saving. My question is how to save to sharedPrefe

Comment: When you add product into cart, you have to store product id into local db or shared preferences, then when you set the data into adapter then you have to check the product id is available or not in local db or shared preferences.

Comment: SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().putBoolean(Id, true).commit();

Comment: Where pid=current product id

Comment: It is turning all buttons to red when i scroll the list

Comment: Add only this lines-

convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
holderForGrid = new ViewHolderGrid(convertView);
convertView.setTag(holderForGrid);

Comment: Remove if(convertView == null){}else{} conditions.

Comment: Hi It is not working, when i scroll list all buttons are turning to red

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        if (catalogList.get(position).isAdded()) {
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Remove");
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnred);
        } else {
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to Cart");
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonsignup);
        }
```